# Make a <div> tag behave like a <br> tag with CSS

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to make a `<div>` tag behave like a stock `<br>` tag with CSS?

Are there any other tags that cannot be mimicked by styling a `<div>`?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this, out of curiosity?

Comment: It's a purely theoretical question; I was just wondering how the default `<br>` styles work

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the `<br />` tag is not interpreted with anything resembling CSS. CSS is parsed by the browsers JavaScript engine; the markup is not. However, you can create styles in CSS that *mimic* other tags (`<hr />`, `<br />`, `<img .../>`, etc)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

add the style `clear:both;`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have a div do almost anything as long as you know exactly what properties to assign to it.

For a fake "br" tag (though I'm not sure why you would ever need this) you can set:

```
.classname {
height: 10px;
width:100%;
display:block;
position:relative;
}
```

Comment: Why height in px and not in em?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure I understand the question, "behave like a `<br />`. You can define the [`display`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#display-prop) attribute of both.

```
display: inline | block;
```

That will determine a line break before and after either element.